# JavaScript single thread performance strongly impacted by load on other cores

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, stress-testing

When I run a single threaded JavaScript application using the Cytoscape.js library, I get **17 FPS** on a 4k display when idle.

However when I run GIMPS/mPrime with one worker with only 4 of 8 cores used, and nothing else active on the machine, I only get **~9 FPS**. So I have 4 cores @100% constantly, and the 5th core is near 100% trough the JavaScript application.

Why is my performance impacted so much when I still have 3 cores free?

The machine is a i7-9700 CPU (no overclock) with 8 Cores without hyperthreading. Benchmarked on Chromium 84.0.4147.89 (64 Bit) on Arch Linux.

[image: idle]
[image: 100% load on 4 cores]